# Visual Studio Debug not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to debug and receive this error message:

[image]

The debugging is working weird. Jumping all over the place

Comment: Simply rebuild your project and debug again.

Comment: May be you're looking for *How to enable Edit and Continue in Visual Studio*

Comment: @HimBromBeere I have done that and still have this problem.

Comment: @Div Edit and Continue is enabled.

Comment: Are you trying to edit file when the solution is getting built? That may be one of the reasons to get this.

Comment: @krw12572 I edited while in debug mode but I have done this before. This time however, this error occured. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: @Junxian Do not do that. How should the debbuger know that you've edited the file? The edits are not compiled and that's why it's not working

Comment: @rbr94 I'm new to this and learnt everything myself. I made a mistake then. How do I solve this problem? I searched over the net but did not manage to find a solution

Comment: This happens because, when solution is built, a file containing symbols(.pdb) is created. This file contains information required to debug and breakpoint related information. When you change your source code, symbols loaded and corresponding source code is no longer same. Thats why this error is shown.

Comment: To get rid of this, do not edit code while program is running or getting built. And if you do edit then just stop current build and build again.

Comment: @krw12572 I did exactly what you said before I posted on here but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you have a different source file than the executable which is run. Maybe yo had some compilation errors, tryed to build the project, you have been asked that if *you want to run the last successful build*, then you had tried to put a breakpoint and debug the application.

First try to solve any compilation errors, and almost *never* run the last successful build as it will not help you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I will post my own solution:

The only way I found that works is to use an old copy of the project where the debugging works fine and transfer the entire code over.

I have tried the following and none of them work:

1. Rebuilding
2. Reset IIS
3. Enable *Edit and Continue* in options (it's enabled by default)

//Not sure why my question got so many downvotes when none of the people here can give a valid answer. Also, I tried searching over the net and could not find a solution to this problem.

Answer (score -2):

Just clean the solution and rebuild it. If that doesn't work then once restart the visual studio. Hope this helps.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for developers, that are used to analyzing issues and providing solutions once that's done. Service deck type of answers (*"Have you tried turning it off and on again?"*) without any analysis whatsoever aren't generally useful.